# x/y axis math calculation for programming purposes

Tags: trigonometry

I am programming a game with "canvas" and i need little Math help doing Coordinates calculation.
Example: 
Given 2D Axis. 
 x1 = 10, y1=10, 
x2 = 20, y2 = 20. 
Length between them is calculating pythagorean theorem: 
Difference = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)(y2-y1)) 
Difference = Math.sqrt(200) = 14.14
Now i need to move on this line with speed of 5/second and update it every 0.1 second. So it would be 
speed = 5 (per second)
reload_rate = 0.1 (seconds)
speed_rate = speed*reload_rate = 5*0.1 = 0.5
Steps = Difference/speed_rate = 14.14/0.5 = 28.28
Steps need to be rounded to higher, so it would be 29. So from starting position to end position it would run in 29 steps, or 29*0.1=2.9 seconds.
What formula would be after first 0.1 second passed? I need the x, y coordinates. 
Will it work if my x1, y1, x2, y2 are mixed negative/positive numbers?

Example now - my game( where is bad formula, but you can get the point)
http://gamegame.herokuapp.com/ , ID testeris, PWD testeris (use maxed-size window). After 10 seconds preloads 5 colored cubes, moving on map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = step/29  // so t goes from 0 at the start to 1 at step 29. 

xx = (1-t) * x1 +  t * x2
yy = (1-t) * y1  + t * y2
```

Then $(xx, yy)$ is the point's position at the given step.

Comment: Thanks :) it was clear and simple to test.

Answer (score 0):

Given initial point $(x_1,y_1)$ and final point $(x_2,y_2)$, first form the vector $(a,b)=(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)$. Then divide $(a,b)$ by $a^2+b^2$ to normalize it. Then the formula for position as a function of time is given by
$$(x,y)=(x_1,y_1)+ts(a,b)$$
where $s$ is the speed, and $t$ is the time. At $t=0$, you get $(x_1,y_1)$.